# Adding fragments without saving to history stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there any way replace a fragment with `FragmentTransaction's replace`, and **NOT** add it to history stack?

I just want my app to dont remember it, when i push back button.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you use FragmentTransaction to add fragment there is [addToBackStack()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html) method, if you don't use it, it won't be in the stack.

```
// it won't add to stack
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
      .commit();

// fragment will be added to stack
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
     .addToBackStack("placeholder")
      commit();
```

Answer (score 7):

By default fragments are not added to backstack. You need to remove call to `addToStack()` from your code.